# RallyRestToolkitFor.NET - Defect Duplicates

Tags: .net, api, rally

I have an MVC application that we are using to display defects to customers. It is using the RallyRestToolkitFor.NET to get this information.

But I need to get a list of all of the duplicates of a defect and I'm not sure how I can acheive this.

Normally, I would get associated objects such as testcases by querying for

```
request = new Request("testcase")
                      {
                          Fetch =
                              new List<string>()
                              {
                                  "FormattedID",
                                  "Name",
                                  "LastRun",
                                  "LastVerdict"
                              },
                          Query =
                              new Query("WorkProduct.FormattedID", Query.Operator.Equals, "DE123")
                      };
```

But I can't see how I can acheive the same for duplicates as there is no 'parent' concept.

Can you help?

Comment: Can you provide some clarification/context as to what you mean by Duplicate Defects? Are you looking to find all Defects that were made as Copies of a specific Defect?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right, The webservice documentation (https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/) shows me that there are duplicates for this defect, I just don't know how to get at them via the RallRestToolkitFor.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code which accesses Duplicates collection on a defect:

```
namespace FindDefectDuplicates
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RallyRestApi restApi;

            restApi = new RallyRestApi("user@co.com", "secret", "https://rally1.rallydev.com", "v2.0");
            String workspaceRef = "/workspace/1111";
            String projectRef = "/project/2222";
            bool projectScopingUp = false;
            bool projectScopingDown = false;

            Request defectRequest = new Request("defect");
            defectRequest.Workspace = workspaceRef;
            defectRequest.Project = projectRef;
            defectRequest.ProjectScopeUp = projectScopingUp;
            defectRequest.ProjectScopeDown = projectScopingDown;

            defectRequest.Fetch = new List<string>()
                {
                    "Name",
                    "FormattedID",
                    "Duplicates"
                };

            defectRequest.Query = new Query("FormattedID", Query.Operator.Equals, "DE123");
            QueryResult queryDefectResults = restApi.Query(defectRequest);
            foreach (var d in queryDefectResults.Results)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("FormattedID: " + d["FormattedID"] + " Name: " + d["Name"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Collection ref: " + d["Duplicates"]._ref);
                Request duplicatesRequest = new Request(d["Duplicates"]);
                QueryResult queryDuplicatesResult = restApi.Query(duplicatesRequest);
                foreach (var duplicate in queryDuplicatesResult.Results)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("FormattedID: " + duplicate["FormattedID"] + " Name: " + duplicate["Name"]);
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```